# Simulation Simulink Matlab

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a regular wave equation to simulate on MATLAB Simulink :

**Equation**:

```
Fw(t) = Awave F(w) cos(wt + g)
```

- `Fw`= Wave existing force;
- `Awave`= Amplitude of wave= Wave Height/2;
- `t` = time= 5 AM, 11 AM, 5 PM, 11 PM;
- `w` = corresponding frequency = `2*pi/T`;
- `T` = Period of wave;
- `g = 0`;

where, `Awave`, `Fw`  and `T` vary with `t`.

Can you please give me an idea? Specially using Simulink MATLAB Function!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feed `Awave`, `Fw`, `T` and `t` as inputs to your MATLAB Function, which should look something like this if I understood correctly:

```
function Fw = wave_fun(Awave,Fw,T,t)
   w = 2*pi/T;
   g = 0; % change if need be
   Fw = Awave * cos(w*t+g);
```

Note that t is the simulation time in s (you can use a [Clock](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/clock.html) block for that). The other variables need to be defined as a function of time in the base workspace and then you can use [From Workspace](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/fromworkspace.html) blocks.

However, this is so simple that a MATLAB Function is unnecessarily complicated in my opinion. Simple mathematical blocks should suffice to combine the inputs and compute the desired output.